# Best way to make and customize JSON responses in Grails?

Tags: json, grails, customization

I did some survey on this problem of how to make/customize JSON response. And there are some ways to do this:

1. Use JSON Marshalling;
2. Use rest-client plugin;
3. Use render() method with closure;
4. Construct the map by self and render the map.

Which is the best way to make/customize JSON responses in Grails? Or there are any other ways to better do this?

Thanks:)

Comment: Depends on your application. There is no "best" way.

Comment: Rightly said @JamesKleeh. You would be able to experience which once is best for you if you start writing test cases for each one of the approach. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best approach is to use custom JSON marshallers for your responses and render responses with `as JSON` converter. This method prevents you from exposing your internal model and adds flexibility in further changes. No plugins are required here. Here is a three part blog post that covers your question: http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/02/15/rendering-json-in-grails-part-3-customise-your-json-with-object-marshallers/.